# Skype bot truncating display

Tags: botframework

I have a bot deployed on Skype. The problem is that Skype truncates long text and shows an ellipsis. Is there a way to avoid this and control size of card?

[image]

Update: I am using Skype desktop application on Windows 10

Comment: Are you using Skype Desktop (Win/Mac)? Skype mobile (iOS/Android)? Skype Web Control? Please be specific.

Comment: @NilsW Added detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every channel has their own limitations on cards. Skype specifically only allows a limited number of chars on a hero card for example(title, subtitle, and text).  As of right now there is not a work around that I know of to either extend the length of the text and/or the size of the card.

Comment: Is there any way to petition for a longer length cutoff in Skype from Microsoft?

Comment: You would have to talk to the skype team about that.  or put in a feature request on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/new).